# ¿Cómo recibir dos respuestas en orden del servidor a través de Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

a ver si me explico porque estoy empezando a conocer AJAX.

Tengo un CRUD que gestiono por AJAX, y la parte de editar, al hacer clic en un usuario concreto de la tabla, muestra un modal con con un formulario y sus datos actuales rellenados que recojo mediante consulta de SELECT por AJAX para, si lo deseamos, modificar alguno y que se guarde mediante UPDATE en la base de datos. Muestro capturas hasta aquí. Pulso sobre editar a Julia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y salen sus datos en un modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí, todo bien. El problema es que si cambio algún dato, y envío la petición para el UPDATE al PHP (es el mismo PHP que hace el SELECT, pero he probando a hacer el SELECT en un archivo y el UPDATE en otro y tampoco), no hace nada. Pongo el código de la petición doble y el PHP:

```
// EDITAR EMPLEADO \\ Al hacer clic, se selecciona por Id de fila de la tabla y se dirige al action de editar empleado con el Id seleccionado
$(document).on('click', '.botonEditarEmpleado', function () {
    // Seleccionamos el Id correspondiente a la fila pulsada
    var IdEmpleadoAjax = this.parentElement.parentElement.firstChild.innerHTML; 
    console.log(IdEmpleadoAjax);

        // Pido al PHP que me devuelva los datos de ese empleado mediante SELECT para rellenar los inputs del formulario
        $.post('../actions/action_actualizar_empleados.php', {IdEmpleadoAjax}, function (response) {
            const editEmpleado = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(editEmpleado);

            $('#editId').val(editEmpleado.editId);
            $('#editNombre').val(editEmpleado.editNombre);
            $('#editApellidos').val(editEmpleado.editApellidos);
            $('#editTelefono').val(editEmpleado.editTelefono);
            $('#editDepartamentoId').val(editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId);
            $('#editHorasContrato').val(editEmpleado.editHorasContrato);
            $('#editEmail').val(editEmpleado.editEmail);
            $('#editContrasena').val(editEmpleado.editContrasena);
            //$('input:radio[name=administra]:checked').val(editEmpleado.editAdministra);
            
            console.log('Administra:' + editEmpleado.editAdministra);

            // Si el SELECT devuelve 1, pintar seleccionado que administra, si no, pintar seleccionado que no administra
            if (editEmpleado.editAdministra == 1) {
                $('#editAdministra').html(
                   '<label>¿Tendrá rol de administrador?&nbsp&nbsp</label>\
                    <label for="administra">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSí</label>\
                    <input type="radio"  name="editAdministra" id="administra" value="1" checked>\
                    <label for="noAdministra">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNo</label>\
                    <input type="radio"  name="editAdministra" id="noAdministra" value="0">\
                    <br><br>'
                );                  
            }
            else
            {
                $('#editAdministra').html(
                   '<label>¿Tendrá rol de administrador?&nbsp&nbsp</label>\
                    <label for="administra">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSí</label>\
                    <input type="radio"  name="editAdministra" id="administra" value="1">\
                    <label for="noAdministra">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNo</label>\
                    <input type="radio"  name="editAdministra" id="noAdministra" value="0" checked >\
                    <br><br>'
                );  
            }
            
            // Pintar seleccionado el departamento según devuelva el SELECT
            console.log('Departamento' + editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId);
            switch (editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId) {
                case '1':
                    //$('#editDepartamentoId').html(
                        editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId = 
                       '<option selected value="1">RRHH</option>\
                        <option value="2">Finanzas</option>\
                        <option value="3">Marketing</option>\
                        <option value="4">Otros</option>\
                        <option value="5">Desarrollo</option>';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId = 
                       '<option value="1">RRHH</option\
                        <option value="2">Finanzas</option>\
                        <option value="3">Marketing</option>\
                        <option value="4">Otros</option>\
                        <option value="5">Desarrollo</option>';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId = 
                    '<option value="1">RRHH</option>\
                        <option value="2">Finanzas</option>\
                        <option selected value="3">Marketing</option>\
                        <option value="4">Otros</option>\
                        <option value="5">Desarrollo</option>';
                    break;
                case '4':
                    editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId = 
                        '<option value="1">RRHH</option>\
                        <option value="2">Finanzas</option>\
                        <option value="3">Marketing</option>\
                        <option selected value="4">Otros</option>\
                        <option value="5">Desarrollo</option>';
                    break;
                case '5':
                    editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId = 
                       '<option value="1">RRHH</option>\
                        <option value="2">Finanzas</option>\
                        <option value="3">Marketing</option>\
                        <option value="4">Otros</option>\
                        <option selected value="5">Desarrollo</option>';
                    break;
              }
              //console.log(editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId);
              //console.log($();
              //console.log('Departamento: ' + editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId);
              $('#editDepartamentoId').html(editEmpleado.editDepartamentoId);

        });

    // Ahora pedimos al PHP realizar las modificaciones hechas en el formulario mediante un UPDATE a BBDD
    $('#modificar').submit(function (e) {
        console.log('enviando');
        
        let postData = {
            administra: $('input:radio[name=editAdministra]:checked').val(),
            nombre: $('#editNombre').val(),
            apellidos: $('#editApellidos').val(),
            telefono: $('#editTelefono').val(),
            departamentoId: $('#editDepartamentoId').find(":selected").val(),
            horasContrato: $('#editHorasContrato').val(),
            email: $('#editEmail').val(),
            contrasena: $('#editContrasena').val()
        };
        $.post('../actions/action_actualizar_empleado.php', {postData}, function (response) {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    });
});
```

y aquí el PHP al que se dirigen las peticiones:

```
<?php
require_once('../config/conexion.php');

    $cnn = Conexion::conectar();

    if (!$cnn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$Id = $_POST['IdEmpleadoAjax'];
$sql = "SELECT e.*, d.NombreDepartamento FROM empleado e join departamento d on e.DepartamentoId = d.Id WHERE e.Id = '$Id'";

$json = array();

$resultado = mysqli_query($cnn, $sql);
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  $json[]=array(
  'editId' => $fila['Id'],
  'editNombre' => $fila['Nombre'],
  'editApellidos' => $fila['Apellidos'],
  'editTelefono' => $fila['Teléfono'],
  'editHorasContrato' => $fila['HorasContrato'],
  'editEmail' => $fila['Email'],
  'editContrasena' => $fila['Contraseña'],
  'editAdministra' => $fila['Administra'],
  'editDepartamentoId' => $fila['DepartamentoId']
  );
}

$jsonString = json_encode($json[0]);
echo $jsonString;



$IdEmpleadoAjax = $_POST['IdEmpleadoAjax'];
$administrador = $_POST['administra'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$horasContrato = $_POST['horasContrato'];
$departamentoId = $_POST['departamentoId'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "UPDATE empleado SET Nombre='$nombre', Apellidos='$apellidos',
Teléfono='$telefono', Email='$email', HorasContrato='$horasContrato',
Administra='$administrador', Contraseña='$contrasena',
DepartamentoId='$departamentoId' WHERE Id = '$IdEmpleadoAjax'";

if (mysqli_query($cnn, $sql))
{
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($cnn))
    {

        echo "Empleado modificado con éxito";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No se ha podido modificar el empleado";
    }
}
else
{
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("error");
    window.location.href="../views/principal_admin.php";
</script>';
die();
}

mysqli_close($cnn);
```

Os pido disculpas por que no se formatee bien el código del JS, no sé qué puede ser.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia:

Tienes tus datos que muestras que los identificas con `IdEmpleadoAjax` una petición Ajax y tu PHP. Tus dos `$.post` *(revisa uno esta hacia **action_actualizar_empleado.php** y otro a **action_actualizar_empleados.php**; con lo anterior y supongo es el mismo script)* ambas peticiones tienen datos distintos; al menos sin importar cual fuera debiera incluir `IdEmpleadoAjax` ya que lo usas (no evalúas si existe y sino tomas otra formas de identificar el elemento a modificar).

Basicamente tienes un faltante de información (al menos para el UPDATE y a que fila aplicarse).

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

En atención a tu comentario; revisar lo siguiente (de la forma que puedas) revises que llega en **`{postData}`** particularmente considero es un objeto por si solo **`postData`** lo que me hace pensar las llaves **{...}** no van.

Realiza lo anterior y como mencione al inicio de esta **actualización** busca con un **vardump** o enviandolo al log del php que llega y como el **postData** incluso su contenido. No olvides que debes agregarle el `IdEmpleadoAjax` ya sea como parte del objeto o parámetro adicional. Tal que , puedas acceder al dato de igual forma o como corresponda para realizar el cambio en `$Id = $_POST['IdEmpleadoAjax'];`

En resumen por el momento y como primer paso, saber como llegan los datos y así sabrás como acceder a ellos.

Sin más por el momento, recibe cordial saludo.

Comment: es cierto @RobertoLeOr, me faltaba una "s", se envía al mismo PHP. Fue una errata de tanto trastear, pero si se la pongo, no funciona. Es como que AJAX solo puede recibir una respuesta y en ese PHP hay dos: la del SELECT que trae los datos y luego la del UPDATE. Me temo que tengo que separar cada acción en un archivo PHP (pero tampoco funciona) o meter cada acción del PHP en una función, pero tampoco he logrado que funcione a la hora de recuperarla en el JS...No sé qué probar ya.